# How can I convert this code to for loop format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I want to alter this code to use a "for" loop:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(0,prosecced_text[0]),  (1,prosecced_text[1]),.. ,(100,prosecced_text[100]) ], ["id", "items"])
```

100 is the length of the `prosecced_text` list.

Answer (score 1):

In general I would advise using a list comprehension to create something like the list you need, but the specific list of tuples you need is exactly what [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) produces (but we have to consume the output of `enumerate` by explicitly constructing a `list` from it in order to get an actual list):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(list(enumerate(prosecced_text)), ["id", "items"])
```

What `enumerate` does is return an iterator that yields `(index,value)` tuples where `index` starts from `0` by default and `value` is each corresponding element of the iterable passed to `enumerate`.

According to a now-deleted comment by [@pault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5858851/pault) the specific method [`spark.createDataFrame`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame) accepts any kind of iterable as its first argument, so you don't even need the enclosing call to `list` in the above specific case. It will just work if you pass `enumerate(prosecced_text)` directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth
# create empty list buffer_list
buffer_list = []
for x in range(101):
    buffer_list.append((x,prosecced_text[x]))


df = spark.createDataFrame(buffer_list, ["id", "items"])
fpGrowth = FPGrowth(itemsCol="items", minSupport=0.5, minConfidence=0.6)
model = fpGrowth.fit(df)
```